# Java 8 Reflections error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection, arguments, invoke, illegalargumentexception

When I execute the following Java code

```
map = new HashMap<>();

cl = new Configuration().getClass();
Method[] m = cl.getMethods();

for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (!m[i].getName().startsWith("get")) {
        m = (Method[]) ArrayUtils.remove(m, i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    try {
        Object[] obj = {};
        String key = m[i].getName().substring(3);
        cl = Class.forName("com.nttdata.tbridge.platformmonitoring.configuration.Configuration");
        map.put(key, m[i].invoke(new Configuration(), obj).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

This code helps to print in my browser files contained by my application. Applying reflection on a class in my project that I call `Configuration` which contains functions for reading files. It seems I'm missing something in the `invoke()` function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd suggest you *start* with logging which method you're about to invoke... then convert the problem into a [mcve]. It seems very unlikely that this is servlet-specific. A console app demonstrating the problem would be much easier to help with.

Comment: Clearly, the method in question takes at least one argument, despite havnig a name starting with "get". Find out what method you're trying to call when you get the error, and look at its signature. Side note: If you're calling a method that doesn't take any, no need for the array, you can pass `null` for the args parameter.

Comment: It seems the for loop where you remove not getter methods contains logical error. You modify array but you don't modify `i`. So result array still contains some methods that are expected to be removed.

Comment: ok let me try to verify all your propositions..thnks men!!!!

Comment: thanks to all of u , y re right. the first for doesn't clean correctly the method array so that it remain some others requiring parameters.. thanks...